# How to fetch API with javascript to find all products with ABV between 5% and 11% and brewed after 2015

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing

I'm trying to use the Javascript fetch API and output the json received and find all products with ABV between 5% and 11% brewed after 2015 with punk API here.

I am not sure how to fetch it and iterate it to filter.

```
const results = document.querySelector("#results");

fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?brewed_after=12-2015&abv_gt=5&abv_lt=11")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

    data.Search.forEach((result) => {
      const beers = `<li>
        <img src="${result.Name}" alt="">
        <p>${result.Picture}</p>
      </li>`;
      results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", beers);
    });
  });
```

Comment: What API are you pulling from? What have you tried and what is going wrong? Do you need help with your code or with the API (we probably don't have experience with the latter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanted to display the data fetched from API by some search applied on it.

It might help you:

```js
var results = document.getElementById("results");

fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?brewed_after=12-2015&abv_gt=5&abv_lt=11")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
  
    data.forEach((result) => {
      var brewed = result.first_brewed; 
      var brewed_year = parseInt(brewed.substring(brewed.indexOf("/")+1));   
      var ingredients = result.ingredients.malt;

      if((result.abv > 5 && result.abv<11) && brewed_year>=2015) {
        const beers = '<li><img src="'+result.image_url+'" alt=""><p>'+result.name+' - '+ingredients[0].name+'</p></li>';
        results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", beers);  
      }
      
    });
  });
```

```html
<style>
img { width:50px; }
</style>

<ul id="results">
</ul>
```

Comment: was wondering why does the syntax here look like that?<p>'+result.name+'</p>   with + sign at the front.

Comment: var brewed_year = parseInt(brewed.substring(brewed.indexOf("/")+1));          can you also sort of explain how you set this variable here thank you

Comment: `<p>'+result.name+'</p>` + sign use to concatenate so I used it to concatenate the string with the variable you can also do this with `${result.name}`

Comment: I used `var brewed_year = parseInt(brewed.substring(brewed.indexOf("/")+1));` variable for getting only year from the `brewed` and then parseInt will convert it into integer to filter the desired year by relational operator.

Comment: thank you! if i were to access the value in this, how would i do that?   "ingredients":{"malt":[{"name":"Propino Pale Malt","amount":{"value":5,"unit":"kilograms"}}

Comment: If you wish to get `ingredients` data so just have to create variable and get values of `result.ingredients` and if want to get values of `malt` so have to add `result.ingredients.malt`

`var ingredients = result.ingredients.malt;
 console.log(ingredients[0].name);`

This will print name of **malt ingredient**.

Comment: Kindly visit this link it will be helpful for you. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: hi!! i've tried but it returned [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] like that from this  "ingredients":{"malt":[{"name":"Propino Pale Malt","amount":{"value":5,"unit":"kilograms"}}

Comment: Basically `ingredients` is an object so it's returning this that's why I mentioned the code above to get value from the `malt` ingredient.

Comment: Have you visited on the link which I've mentioned above?

Comment: yes I've tried the codes above and viewed the link, its still returning the object.

Comment: const beers = '<li><img src="'+result.image_url+'" alt=""><h3>'+result.name+'</h3><p>'+result.ingredients.malt; console.log(ingredients[0].name);+'</p><p>'+result.abv+'</p><p>'+result.description+'</p></li>';
        results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", beers);

Comment: and set the variable as   var ingredients = result.ingredients.malt; console.log(ingredients[0].name);

Comment: I've updated the answer you can check it, it's working.